# Meteor return name from previous query

Tags: javascript, html, mongodb, meteor

I'm doing a small app where I display friend requests and an 'accept/reject' button beside each request.

here's my `Template.notifications.helpers`:

```
listRequests: function(){
        return Notifications.find({toUser: Meteor.userId()});
    }
```

and here's my notifications (where I display notifications for friend requests) template:

```
<template name="notifications">
    {{#each listRequests}}
        <p>{{displayUserName}}
            <span id="fromUserId"><strong>{{fromUser}}</strong></span> sent you a friend request.
            <button class="btn btn-primary" id="btnAcceptRequest">Accept</button>
            <button class="btn btn-danger" id="btnRejectRequest">Reject</button>
        </p>
        <p>{{createdAt}}</p>
    {{/each}}
</template>
```

And here's my `user` collection:

```
{    
 "_id": "zaSuTBgRh3oQcPSkh",
  "emails": [
    {
      "address": "johnsmith@yahoo.com",
      "verified": false
    }
  ],
  "profile": {
    "firstname": "John",
    "lastname": "Smith"
  }
}
```

Currently, this code works. The issue is that it only displays the `_id` of the user who sent the request, thus, `fromUser`. What I wanted to do is display the firstname and lastname of the requesting user but I don't know where to go from here.

Of course, I tried replacing `{{fromUser}}` with `{{profile.firstname profile.lastname}}` and `return Meteor.users.find({});` on the `Template helpers` but it does not work. Can anyone help me with this? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Could you post what your Notifications collection looks like? Is it simply `toUser` and `fromUser`?

Comment: yes it just contains `toUser`, `fromUser` , and a `createdAt`

Answer (score 2):

You need a helper that does the lookup of the other user document and returns the appropriate values:

```
Template.notifications.helpers({
  fromUserName: function(){
    var fromUser = Meteor.users.findOne({ _id: this.fromUser });
    if ( fromUser ){
      return fromUser.profile.firstname + ' ' + fromUser.profile.lastname;
    }
  }
});
```

Note that if you have removed *autopublish* you must also be publishing the profile field (at least) from the user collection from the server and then subscribing to that on the client.

Comment: How would you render that on `blaze` then?

Comment: `{{fromUserName}}` in the `notifications` template.